# How to ensure either all things are done, or none is done?

Tags: node.js, transactions, microservices

The title might be misleading (I couldn't come up with a better title to be honest) so please read my explanation:

Let's say we are trying to create a user and also update the cache:

1. Create user and insert to database.
2. Update the cache with created user.

**OR**

We are trying to publish an event after user is created (for example in microservices)

1. Create user and insert to database.
2. Publish an event with created user.

**OR**

We are trying to do `n` things and we want to ensure either all of them get completed or none.

1. Create user and insert to database.
2. Update cache.
3. Send an email.
4. Send SMS.
5. Publish an event, ... ( the list goes on )

In a perfect world where there are no failures, we can just write them in order and that's it, but what happens when we have a failure after user creation is complete? (Before adding to cache OR Sending the event, etc)

These examples are made up and are for the cache example:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1
};
const user = database.createUser(data);
// Power goes out here (or any kind of failure)
cache.setCache(user);
```

Here, We've successfully created the user but failed to update the cache.

Let's give another example using database transactions:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1
};
const transaction = database.startTransaction();
try {
  const user = database.createUser(data);
  cache.setCache(user);
// Power goes out here (or any kind of failure)
  transaction.commit();
} catch(err) {
  transaction.rollback();
}
```

Here, We've successfully updated the cache but the user was never created because of the failure.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Each microservice has to support transactions. So you can commit or rollback.
https://www.baeldung.com/transactions-across-microservices

Comment: There's a point where you just have to have a restartable/retry process though, like the send email/sms examples steps where there's no take backs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with microservices, the usual ACID transactions that we are used to work with won't apply. Instead you could have a look at BASE transactions.

See here : https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/06/brewer-cap-theorem-base/

> An alternative to ACID is BASE:
>
> - **B**asic **A**vailability
> - **S**oft-state
> - **E**ventual consistency
>
> Rather than requiring consistency after every transaction, it is enough for the database to eventually be in a consistent state. (Accounting systems do this all the time. It’s called “closing out the books.”) It’s OK to use stale data, and it’s OK to give approximate answers.

Technically it means that you're gonna have to find a clean way to deal with failure, for example by sending Events in case of failure (which means the user you created should be removed from the cache, or event send an email saying there's been an error).

We often see examples in orders or payments system, where you can receive an email saying that the order could not be processed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but let's ignore the "microservice" aspect for a second, let's say I want to create a user and send an email to welcome the newly registered user to the website, what happens when right after I send the email ( before logging it somewhere that the email was sent ) power goes out? I can have some backup plan to redo the process and resend the email, but this way the user has gotten two emails, my question is, is it something that can be prevented ( without a huge amount of effort ) or do we just accept these kind of "rare" things as controlled damage?

Comment: If you're using event "streaming", you should send the email after commiting to the database (publish user signed up event => save to the db, publish user registration success event => send email). You could also use event "sourcing", then an event that is stored becomes source of truth, and triggers the db transaction and the email process. The source of truth is what matters in both example.